# How to handle errors when they are NOT the only value returned by a function?

Tags: go, variables, error-handling

I have created a function to handle errors that looks like this:

```
func handleErr(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error:", e)
    }
}
```

For functions that only return an error, I can do the following:

```
handleErr(os.Chdir("Documents"))
```

However, for functions that also return other values and not only an error, I have to spread my code over two lines, like this:

```
s, e := os.Getwd()
handleErr(e)
```

Is there a way to condense the above two lines into one?

Comment: *"Is there a way to condense the above two lines into one?"* -- No, not yet. Next year, when Go 1.18 ships with type parameters you'll probably be able to do that. But not with Go 1.17, which is the current version. Example using type parameters: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/p53MxrtPgsO

Answer (score 2):

Please note that it's not possible to uniformly handle the error *and* return a dynamically typed value *at the same time*. `handleErr()` could only return a value of type `interface{}`, further type assertion would be needed to extract a concrete type from it. As noted by mkopriva's comment, generics is needed to make the return type "dynamic".

The below answer only handles the error, but discards the other return value(s).

#### If you can modify `handleErr()`

Add another parameter to `handlerErr()` of `interface{}` type. Any value is assignable to `interface{}`:

```
func handleErr(i interface{}, e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error:", e)
    }
}
```

Lets use this example function:

```
func foo(fail bool) (int, error) {
    if fail {
        return 0, errors.New("fail")
    }
    return 0, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
handleErr(foo(false))
fmt.Println("First is OK")
handleErr(foo(true))
fmt.Println("Second is OK")
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/r05I2ssW7Vx)):

```
First is OK
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Error:fail
```

`handleErr(foo(false))` is possible and is valid, because [Spec: Calls:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls)

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method `g` are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method `f`, then the call `f(g(parameters_of_g))` will invoke `f` after binding the return values of `g` to the parameters of `f` in order. The call of `f` must contain no parameters other than the call of `g`, and `g` must have at least one return value. If `f` has a final `...` parameter, it is assigned the return values of `g` that remain after assignment of regular parameters.

#### If you can't modify `handleErr()`

You can write a helper function which reduces 2 return values to one:

```
func reduceTwoParams(i interface{}, err error) error {
    return err
}
```

You may use this with any functions that return 2 values where second is `error`, because all values are assignable to `interface{}`.

Testing it:

```
handleErr(reduceTwoParams(foo(false)))
fmt.Println("First is OK")
handleErr(reduceTwoParams(foo(true)))
fmt.Println("Second is OK")
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tQ8YK8AkF7i)):

```
First is OK
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Error:fail
```

If you want to handle functions with 3 return values, you have to write another helper:

```
func reduceThreeParams(i, j interface{}, err error) error {
    return err
}
```

Comment: I believe what OP was asking is how to reduce it to one line while still being able to retain the primary return value. i.e. Why call `os.Getwd` if you're not getting the wd?

Comment: @mkopriva Well, yes, in that case generics are needed.

Comment: ... and I know one could return `interface{}` and then type-assert, but at that point I don't see the point of `handleErr`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you here, but I'm genuinely wondering what your thoughts are on these kinds of error handling functions? Personally I never use them, and they do not feel like idiomatic Go at all. Given your extensive knowledge and, I assume, experience, do *you* find these to be a good approach? Do you see them a lot in "real world" projects?

Comment: @mkopriva I rarely see them in real projects, and I'm against them. This is not the proper way to handle errors. Each error should be handled differently, and this is exactly the opposite. The 2 cases when this is acceptable in my opinion are when writing short examples / demos (when the focus is **not** on handling errors), and during app initialization when the occurrence of an error is a show-stopper (when logging the error and terminating is OK).